# using promises with getCollection

Tags: rally

I'm trying to figure out how to apply the promises infrastructure in the case where I'm looping through a list of portfolio items to extract data for highcharts use and need to retrieve data from the related user stories.  The goal is to create a way to not attempt to instantiate the chart object until all async callbacks are completed.  Here's a code snippet illustrating what I'm trying to do - in this example, the getCollection() method's callback function is not being executed until all of the outer loop features have been retrieved.

```
_.each(records, function(feature) {
    var rname = (feature.get('Release')) ? feature.get('Release')._refObjectName: "None";
    //various other feature record extraction steps
    feature.getCollection('UserStories').load({
      fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'InProgressDate','AcceptedDate'],
      callback: function(stories, operation, success){
      Ext.Array.each(stories, function(story) {
        var storyname = story.get('FormattedID') + ': ' + story.get('Name');
        //   other chart data extraction steps
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out the guide in the docs on working with promises, especially the section on retrieving hierarchical data:

https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/guide/promises-section-retrieving-hierarchical-data

The basic idea is to keep an array of all the promises representing the child collection store loads and then to use a Deft.Promise.all to wait for them all to finish before continuing.

So something like this, based on your code above:

```
var childStoryPromises = [];
_.each(records, function(feature) {
    var rname = (feature.get('Release')) ? feature.get('Release')._refObjectName: "None";
    // various other feature record extraction steps
    var userStoriesStore = feature.getCollection('UserStories');
    var promise = userStoriesStore.load({
        fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'InProgressDate','AcceptedDate']
    });
    childStoryPromises.push(promise);
    feature.userStoriesStore = userStoriesStore;  //save reference for later
});

//wait for all stores to load
Deft.Promise.all(childStoryPromises).then({
    success: function() {
        _.each(records, function(feature) {
            var userStories = feature.userStoriesStore.getRange();
            //extract user story data here
        });
    },
    scope: this
});
```

Comment: This looks like it is exactly what I needed!  I'll plug this approach into my code and see what happens.  Thank you.

Comment: Tried it and it worked like a charm.  Thanks for getting me around my brain-lock!  Built a really sweet timeline view of all features and stories for one of our programs.

Comment: nice!  glad i could help!